# displaying only one product per row in magento

Tags: css

we used some marketplace extension , so

here in this following link, you can see only 1 product is displaying per row.

i want to display 3 products per row .

http://hotwheelstoys.in/totaltoys2/var/www/html/totaltoys/marketplace/seller/collection/kidsdial2

is there any css problem with that page as it is displaying only one per product per row?

please help me to display 3 products per row and help me to display "add to cart" button below as like here :

http://hotwheelstoys.in/totaltoys2/var/www/html/totaltoys/girls-toys.html

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert of Magento so I'm not sure how the code is build but the problem of the products listed only 1 per row depends on a "div" with class "fieldset".

In the code of the page you have:

```
<div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset" style="padding: 0;">....</div>
```

that contains all your products, if you check the css has this rule:

```
.fieldset {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
}
```

if you set the width to 100% you will see that more products per row will show